# What is the difference between [president] and [presidential]?

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

There seem to be a [presidential](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/presidential) tag, in addition to the [president](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/president) tag.

What are their differences and should [presidential](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/presidential) be made a synonym of [president](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/president)?

Comment: I think it should be merged.

Comment: I think it should be made a synonym, too.

Comment: Scanning through the tag, it appears that the overwhelming majority of 'presidential' tags should be 'president' instead. https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/14017/all-time-highest-net-worth-of-a-presidential-cabinet-in-constant-dollars appears to be a case where 'presidential' was used correctly and distinctly from 'president'. A large number of the problem tags are really a case of using two tags, 'election' and 'presidential' instead of 'presidential-election'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[presidential](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/presidential) is [now a synonym](https://politics.stackexchange.com/tags/president/synonyms) of [president](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/president).